Why does `docker logout` remove credentials, even if it is configured to use a keychain/password manager?
By default, when you login, the credentials are stored to ~/.docker/config.json (in Ubuntu). When you logout, the credentials are removed again. I understand that is for security, so you don't have the credentials stored as plain text once you are done.
When docker is configured to use a password manager (as a secret service), docker login with username and password will save the credentials to the password manager. If the credentials are already in the password manager, you can do a straight docker login without typing in the username and password. It will use the credentials from the password manager. So far so good.
What I don't understand is why docker logout says Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/ and tries to removes the credentials from the password manager. It triggers a popup from my password manager saying Do you really want to delete the entry "https://index.docker.io/v1/" for good?
Isn't the point of the password manager the convenience of storing passwords and not have to manually type them in to login? If it deletes the credentials each time when logging out, doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of having a password manager? Can docker be configured to, not delete credentials, and if so, how?
